# Why my Row with the children Rows not visible in the screen in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen with Text title and Text content and, below that in a parent Row I am trying to display 4 different rows on single line inside the Parent row. But now when I add Spacer none of my Rows get displayed below the content.It's showing like this [image]

I want those Rows to be displayed like this shown in this screen below the content.[image]

Below is my code

```
package com.example.speechrecognition.speechscreens

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.speechrecognition.Destinations
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1(navController: NavController) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(top = 69.dp)) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(start = 21.dp, top = 13.dp, end = 25.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { _, offset, _, _ ->
                        offsetX += offset.x
                        if (offsetX.absoluteValue >= swipeThreshold) {
                            if (offsetX > 0) {
                                navController.navigate(Destinations.speechscreen2)
                            }
                            offsetX = 0f
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Please read the following text:",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(28.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
            Text(
                text = "One morning Dorothy crossed the hall of the palace and knocked on the door of another girl named Trot. When told to enter, Dorothy found that Trot had company, an old sailor-man with a wooden leg who was sitting by the open window puffing smoke from a pipe.",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    lineHeight = 40.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                    color = Color(0xFF080808)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(top = 9.dp, end = 25.dp)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) // This adds a constant distance

        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want column instead of parent row?

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))` and this will occupy all the remaining space because the `weight` is set to `1f` and the `Row` is visible at the end of the screen you can see in your preview as well.

If you want to place the `Row` below some height from `Text` then you can use `.size(16.dp)` for the `Spacer` and this will gain the defined height.